# How to redirect %20 or White space automatically to + or - with htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need to redirect automatically lots of url like /file%20name/ ore /file name/ to /file+name/ or /file-name/.

How can I do this with .htacess ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
Options +FollowSymlinks

# executes repeatedly as long as there are more than 1 spaces in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s+(\S* .*)$" $1+$2 [N,NE]

# executes when there is exactly 1 space in URI
RewriteRule "^(\S*)\s(\S*)$" /$1+$2 [L,R=302,NE]
```

- R=301 will redirect with https status 301
- L will make last rule
- NE is for no encoding URI

Comment: [QSA] is not needed if you don't add parameters in the URL rewritting. `This flag forces the rewrite engine to append a query string part of the substitution string to the existing string, instead of replacing it.` `?` will replace by <empty>, `?a=1` replaces with `a=1` and `?a=1 [QSA]` by `a=1&<other query string from the first call>`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
RewriteRule file\ name\ http://example.com/file+name [R=301,NC,NE,L]
```

Edit after comment:

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^\ ]*)\ (.*)$ $1-$2 [E=rspace:yes,N]
```

Comment: Yes ok @manojlds but this is not automatic for all url.
I need to automatically redirect all kind of URL that contain space.

Comment: Yes but how ? This is the question :)

Comment: Ok thanks I'll try but only after the apache upgrade to 2.2.7.