# How to rewrite url with space in it with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

If 'localhost/a/something' is the url, the .htaccess rewrites it to 'localhost/a/1.php?food=something'

If I type in 'localhost/a/something something' it gives me a 404 error.

My current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /a/

RewriteRule ^([A-z]+)$ 1.php?food=$1 [L]
```

How can I 'localhost/a/something something' to 'localhost/a/1.php?food=something+something'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please have a look at:

[How to redirect %20 or White space automatically to + or - with htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689528/how-to-redirect-20-or-white-space-automatically-to-or-with-htaccess)

This seems to do what you are trying to do...

Answer (score 0):

> Try this rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^article/with\ 1.php$ /food/1.php [R=301,L]
```