# Allow space and other special characters in htaccess url rewrite

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Hi everyone i have this URL: `orderprod_cntr/147/ok2%20-%20val1%20val2%20val3%20val4`

When ever i open this URL i get 404 error.

The htaccess rule that i am using at present is:

```
RewriteRule orderprod_cntr/([-\w]+)/([-\w]+)/?$   controller/orderprod_cntr.php?id1=$1&id2=$2 [L]
```

The error is occurring due to `%20` in the URL, without it works fine.
Please tell me the correct rule to use for the above url.
Thanks

Comment: A comment before down voting will be helpful for me to edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tweak your regex like this:

```
RewriteRule orderprod_cntr/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ controller/orderprod_cntr.php?id1=$1&id2=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: The above regular expression means allow any special character in the url paramters right?

Comment: Yes it will allow anything except `/`. Glad it worked. Question was fair and unfairly downvoted. So +1 from my side

Comment: @anubhava can you check my question if you have a time please : [QUESTION](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49675246/what-i-need-to-do-in-order-to-open-urls-with-special-characters)

Answer (score 0):

Based on [How to redirect %20 or White space automatically to + or - with htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689528/how-to-redirect-20-or-white-space-automatically-to-or-with-htaccess) I suggest:

```
RewriteRule orderprod_cntr/((-|\w|%20)+)/((-|\w|%20)+) controller/orderprod_cntr.php?id1=$1&id2=$4 [L]
```