# How to remove white space and - in start of the String .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have lot of URL that are having www.example.com/info/range/-string or www.example.com/info/range/ string, I want to remove white space of - in start of the string, how I can do this with .htaccess, I have tried this method but not working for me.
[How to redirect %20 or White space automatically to + or - with htaccess?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5689528/how-to-redirect-20-or-white-space-automatically-to-or-with-htaccess)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove hyphen or space before `string` and after `info/range/` then you can use this redirect rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(info/range)/[-\s]+(.+)$ /$1/$2 [L,NC,R=302]
```

I would also advice you to update the question with clear examples and your current .htaccess.

Comment: Thank you Anubhava, you are always Helpful :)